# QTextEdit background color change also the color of scrollbar

Tags: c++, qt

I want the QtextEdit in my app to be green so I set the stylesheet to

```
background-color: rgb(109, 255, 99);
```

However this also change the background color of the scrollbars and even when I click mouse right button in the textedit the menu that is shown is also green and that is not what I expected.

I'm using *Qt Designer* to design gui and then I used the *uic* to generate c++ file.

in the c++ file it looks like this:

```
textEdit->setAutoFillBackground(false);
textEdit->setStyleSheet(QString::fromUtf8("background-color: rgb(109, 255, 99);"));
textEdit->setReadOnly(true);
```

Anybody know how to set the background color only for the area where text would be?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All child objects of your text edit inherit the stylesheet, so all children (e.g. context menus) will have a green background.

You should select your QTextEdit only in your stylesheet, i.e.

```
textEdit->setStyleSheet("QTextEdit { background-color: rgb(109, 255, 99) }");
```

Note that you can set the stylesheet at application level, too, so that all QTextEdit's in your app will have your specified background:

```
qApp->setStyleSheet("QTextEdit { background-color: rgb(109, 255, 99) }");
```

Comment: this did not seem to work for me because the buttons were still colored--had to do this:              QPalette* palette = new QPalette();
            palette->setColor(QPalette::Base,QColor(0,0,0));
            palette->setColor(QPalette::Text,QColor(128,128,128));
            textEditor->setPalette(*palette);
 for a grey text on black background, this didnt color any of the buttons. I think your answer was right, but there seems that somehow buttons are included in the 'QTextEdit' class.