# How to set Qtextedit background color?

Tags: html, qt

I noticed that if in HTML we use type bgcolor="#ffd814" then in textedit the background color will change to the color. How can I get same result from QAction and QColorDialog?

I used this

```
void MainWindow::on_actionBackground_Color_triggered()
{    
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::white,this);
    QPalette palette;
    palette.setColor(QPalette::Base,color);
    if(color.isValid())
        ui->textEdit->setPalette(palette);
}
```

But it does not change HTML, so after closing and opening the file background is white.

**Remark:** using bgcolor="#ffd814" in < body bgcolor="#ffd814" > does not change the scrollbar color in textedit.

If we use QColor::name it will return in QString format color name (#ffd814) how can we put it in a html. for example

```
void MainWindow::on_actionText_Color_triggered()
{
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::white,this);
    if(color.isValid())
        ui->textEdit->setTextColor(color);
}
```

this changes color of selected text and saves it in html, so changes we made in textedit are remembered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554435/qtextedit-background-color-change-also-the-color-of-scrollbar

Comment: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/2196-Qt4-QTextEdit-background-color

Comment: I already seen them, they don't work properly as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Create your QPalette with related object.

```
QPalette palette = ui->textEdit->pallette();
```

Here is a working example;

```
QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor(Qt::white,this); // in here your color pallete will open..

QPalette p = ui->textEdit->palette(); // define pallete for textEdit.. 
p.setColor(QPalette::Base, Qt::red); // set color "Red" for textedit base
p.setColor(QPalette::Text, color); // set text color which is selected from color pallete
ui->textEdit->setPalette(p); // change textedit palette
```

Comment: The correct method signature should be `ui->textEdit->palette()`